# Rust type conversion

Tags: rust

Is it possible to convert type T into generic type without use of into() ?

```
struct MyType<T>(T);

impl<T> From<T> for MyType<T> {
    fn from(v: T) -> Self {
        Self(v)
    }
}

#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn main() {
    let test1 = MyType(12);
    //let test2: MyType<i32> = 12; // why is this not working
    let test3: MyType<i32> = 12.into();
    let test4 = MyType::from(12);
    
}

fn test_fnc_1() -> MyType<i32> {
    12 // not working
    12.into()
}
```

I want to do "test2", but this is not possible. I have to do "test3".

Another sample, I thought it is somehow possible, is in test_func_1.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=34bab76c16fc85e020bab0f373475af3)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not possible is because the cost of converting a value into your time can be arbitrarily large. Implicit conversion would hide this cost, which is not desirable for system language.

As far as I know there are no plans to add implicit conversion into Rust.

Answer (score 1):

Rust is fairly reserved about implicit conversions. In [Type Coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) in the Rust Reference you can see most of them are dictated by the compiler, with `Deref` being the only user-defined conversion that may be done implicitly. An exception of course is the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator) which does invoke a `From` conversion.

There is no implicit `From` conversion that is called when passing arguments, returning a value, or assigning to a variable. You will have to use `.into()` or `T::from()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is implicit type conversion, which isn't possible in Rust. As you've seen, you have to explicitly construct types at some point (i.e. `MyType(...)` in your example), and that can be done either directly or with a function call.

There are some special cases where implicit coercion occurs, but these are generally only when dealing with references or traits, not concrete value types.

Comment: I'm quite new to Rust...

I have a own error type and use 
`#[error(transparent)] OtherError(#[from] anyhow::Error)`

I can use `?` in my functions and any error is automatically converted into my OtherError.
I thought, this is also possible in the same way for my own type.

But will use now into()

Comment: Question mark operator calls `Into::into` automatically, yes.